# Filter array of objects by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects:

```
const obj = [
        { name: 'Test', age: 25 },
        { name: 'App', age: 27 },
        { name: 'Const', age: 28 },
];
```

and I have the other one:

```
const value = [
        { surname: 'Test', age: 54 },
        { surname: 'Back', age: 54 },
        { surname: 'Front', age: 54 },
        { surname: 'Const', age: 54 },
        { surname: 'App', age: 54 },
];
```

Now, I want to leave in the second array only objects,
which have name === surname and the other ones delete.
Keys must be different, but the values in them must be the same.
For example: {name: "Test", age: 25} === {surname: "Test", age: 54}(it's just an example)
How to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const obj = [
  { name: 'Test', age: 25 },
  { name: 'App', age: 27 },
  { name: 'Const', age: 28 },
];

let value = [
  { surname: 'Test', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'Back', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'Front', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'Const', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'App', age: 54 },
];

const names = obj.map(el => el.name);

value = value.filter(el => names.includes(el.surname));
```

or like this:

```
const obj = [
  { name: 'Test', age: 25 },
  { name: 'App', age: 27 },
  { name: 'Const', age: 28 },
];

const names = obj.map(el => el.name);

const value = [
  { surname: 'Test', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'Back', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'Front', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'Const', age: 54 },
  { surname: 'App', age: 54 },
].filter(el => names.includes(el.surname));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filter and some:

```js
const myArrayFiltered = obj.filter( el => {
  return value.some( f => {
    return f.surname === el.name;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your have to use `filter` and see if there is a key in the second list. 
And don't forget to reassign the result of `filter()` to the `value` list as the filter doesn't change the original list, but returns a new, filtered one.

```
value = value.filter(oneVal => obj.find(o => o.name === oneVal.surname))
```

More on [filter() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

Use embedded Javascript's [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods:

```
value.filter(k => 
   obj.find(v => v.name === k.surname)
)
```

This basically says "filter all values from `value` array that match this criteria". And the criteria is "find values in `obj` where name equals surname".